# Secondary "o"steoporosis or Secondary "O"steoporosis

Tags: capitalization

At a [website](https://www.sheffield.ac.uk/FRAX/tool.aspx?lang=en), some nouns have been written in capital and some in small. Is there any specific reasons for it?

For example, these are some written phrases in the website:
7. Current "S"moking
9. Rheumatoid "a"rthritis
10. Secondary "o"steoporosis

Update: I marked @James K reply as the answer as owner of the website confirmed they were typos.

Comment: Those are typos. The word is: osteoporosis. Only the first words are capitalized in your list. Please correct the typos.

Comment: I found no typos. These are terms used in the website. My question was why letters in " " are not following the same rule.

Comment: You would have to ask whoever wrote that form, and they probably don't even realise it's inconsistent. Those types of form are usually written by programmers, and written quickly (and therefore slightly carelessly).

Comment: I thought they would have said why you had not search for the rules before asking us. I did not know they were typos and thought they had followed a style guide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those are just very minor inconsistencies (or mistakes) The person who typed in the headings used different capitalisation rules on different lines.  This is poor style, but most people wouldn't even notice.

Comment: Downvoters,  any suggestions for improvement?

Answer (score 2):

The names of medical conditions and diseases are left lowercase. Only conditions or diseases that include a proper name, (such as Alzheimer's, Parkinson's or Crohn's, which are named for the physician that identified them), should be capitalized.

This [style guide](http://web.mit.edu/course/21/21.guide/capitals.htm) confirms:

> Do not capitalize medical terms except for any part of a term consisting of a proper noun:
>    - infectious mononucleosis
>    - brachial plexus
>    - Parkinson's disease